# Searching for a known path in OrientDB

Tags: path, dns, orientdb

I'm experimenting with the idea of storing a DNS hierarchy in an OrientDB graph and am having trouble finding the appropriate place to add a new vertex for a given domain.

I am starting with this structure:

```
CREATE CLASS Zone EXTENDS V
CREATE CLASS Subdomain_of EXTENDS E
CREATE VERTEX Zone CONTENT {name: '.'}      #12:0
CREATE VERTEX Zone CONTENT {name: 'com'}        #12:1
CREATE VERTEX Zone CONTENT {name: 'net'}        #12:2
CREATE VERTEX Zone CONTENT {name: 'org'}        #12:3
CREATE VERTEX Zone CONTENT {name: 'example'}    #12:4
CREATE VERTEX Zone CONTENT {name: 'www'}        #12:5
CREATE EDGE Subdomain FROM #12:1 TO #12:0
CREATE EDGE Subdomain FROM #12:2 TO #12:0
CREATE EDGE Subdomain FROM #12:3 TO #12:0
CREATE EDGE Subdomain FROM #12:4 TO #12:1
CREATE EDGE Subdomain FROM #12:5 TO #12:4
```

[Example DNS Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qJFr.png)

I want to create a saved function that will take a domain name string as input and add relevant subdomains to the graph.

Imagine I want to add domain "mail.example.com". The function would need to first search to see if the path .com.example.mail existed - if not, it should then check .com.example and add a new vertex for "mail" with a subdomain edge to the "example" vertex.

Is there a way to search for a leaf node, based upon a specific path? Something akin to Neo4j/Cypher syntax:

```
MATCH
(:Zone {name: ‘.’})<-[Subdomain]-(:Zone {name: ‘com’})<-[:Subdomain]-(a:Zone {name: ‘example’})
RETURN (ID(a))
```

Thanks,

Charles

Comment: About the function, for you is more useful developed in Java or Javascript? 
I did not understand what you mean by 'to search for a leaf node', you want to search if for example there is a 'vertex leaf' which is called "www"?

Answer (score 1):

With this Java function should add the new vertices if not already present.

```
public class DomainInternet {

    static final String REMOTE = "remote:localhost/";
    static final String NOMEDB = "domain"; // 2.1.9 community
    static final String CURRENTPATH = REMOTE + NOMEDB;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        OrientGraphNoTx g = new OrientGraphFactory(CURRENTPATH).getNoTx();

        addDomain(g, "mail.example.com");

        System.out.println("End!");
    }

    public static void addDomain(OrientGraphNoTx g, String newDomain) {

        // ---------------------check if path is already present
        // put in a list the single word
        List<String> listDomain = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(newDomain.split("([.])")));
        //reverse = "com; example; mail"
        Collections.reverse(listDomain);


        //set variable used by query to find if domain is already present
            Iterable<Vertex> level = null;
            List<OrientVertex> listaVertex = new ArrayList<OrientVertex>();     
            String queryFirst = "select expand(in('Subdomain_of')) from Zone where name = ";
            String name = "";
            boolean finded = false;
        //set variable used by add new domain
            OrientVertex addVertex;
            String nodePrec = ".";



        for(int i=0; i<listDomain.size(); i++) {
            //from "." 
            level = g.command(new OSQLSynchQuery<Vertex>(queryFirst+"'"+nodePrec+"'")).execute();
            CollectionUtils.addAll(listaVertex, level.iterator());

            for (int ind = 0; ind<listaVertex.size(); ind++) {
                name = listaVertex.get(ind).getProperty("name");

                if(name.equals(listDomain.get(i))){
                    finded = true;
                    break;
                } 
            }
            // if not finded
            if (!finded) {

                //add vertex
                addVertex = g.addVertex("class:Zone");
                addVertex.setProperties("name", listDomain.get(i)); 

                //add edge
                Map<String, Vertex> vertices = new HashMap<String, Vertex>();
                for (Vertex v : g.getVertices()){
                    vertices.put(v.getProperty("name").toString(), v);
                }

                g.addEdge("class:Subdomain_of", vertices.get(listDomain.get(i)), vertices.get(nodePrec), "Subdomain_of");
            }

            //set new name for next link
            nodePrec = listDomain.get(i);
            listaVertex.clear();
            finded = false;
        }

        g.shutdown();
    }

}
```

**EDIT 1**

The same function made in JAVASCRIPT

- Create a new JS function (named for example 'AddNewDomain')
- Add the parameter named 'nameNewDomain';

  ```
   var gdb = orient.getGraphNoTx();
   print("Insert new domain: '" + nameNewDomain + "'");

  // ---------------------check if path is already present
  var listDomain = nameNewDomain.split('.');
  listDomain.reverse();

  var listaVertex;
  var queryFirst = "select expand(in('Subdomain_of')) from Zone where name = ";
  var name = "";
  var finded = false;
  var nodePrec = ".";

  for (i = 0; i < listDomain.length; i++) {
      // from "."
      listaVertex = gdb.command("sql", queryFirst + "'" + nodePrec + "'");

      for (ind = 0; ind < listaVertex.length; ind++) {
          name = listaVertex[ind].getProperty("name");

          if (name.equals(listDomain[i])) {
              finded = true;
              break;
          }
      }
      // if not finded
      if (!finded) {
          // add vertex
          gdb.command("sql", "insert into Zone (name) values('" + listDomain[i] + "')");

          // add edge
          gdb.command("sql", "create edge Subdomain_of from (select from Zone where name = '" + listDomain[i]
                  + "') to (select from Zone where name = '" + nodePrec + "')");
      }

      // set new name for next link
      nodePrec = listDomain[i];
      listaVertex = "";
      finded = false;
  }
  ```

In the Tab 'browse' in studio, recall the function:

> select AddDomain("mail3.example2.com")

Comment: Thanks! This seems to exactly what is needed. Is there a way that I could use JavaScript to do the same job, so that I can store it as a function in OrientDB?

Comment: ok, I'm trying to do it in javascript. as soon as i finish, i will pass you the function

Comment: sorry for delay, i edited answer with "EDIT 1" that contains the JS function to add new domain follow the same logic writtend in the previus java code.